# I am no stranger to/ I am not stranger to

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I am no stranger to smth.
>
> I am not stranger to smth.

Which one is correct? Or do they have different meanings depending on the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I am no stranger to sm[i]th" is correct. The second would be correct if phrased "I am not a stranger to sm[i]th." The article is critical.